# Add single quotes to results in a column from a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I currently have the following SQL:

```
SELECT opportunities.ref FROM opportunities GROUP BY opportunities.ref
```

which returns the following results:

```
OP10
OP252
OP52905
OP42
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
'OP10'
'OP252'
'OP52905'
'OP42'
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT opportunities.ref FROM opportunities
CASE WHEN opportunities.ref IS NOT NULL THEN "'"+opportunitiesref+"'"
GROUP BY opportunities.ref
```

but this does not work.

I do not want to update the column, or use any @declare functions as this. I am currently using SQL server 2008. Im not sure how to go about this. Help?

Comment: how about this? select concat("'", opportunities.ref, "'") ...

Comment: ANSI SQL: `... '''' || opportunities.ref || '''' ...`.

Comment: If you are using a column from a result set to populate an argument of a function parameter in SQL, you don't need to surround with quotes.  Just leave as is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using SQL SERVER then modify your query according to below :

```
SELECT opportunities.ref FROM opportunities
CASE WHEN opportunities.ref IS NOT NULL THEN ''''+opportunitiesref+''''
GROUP BY opportunities.ref
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using SQL SERVER then refer below queries. it will work.

1)

```
SELECT opportunities.ref,concat('''',opportunities.ref,'''')
FROM opportunities
GROUP BY opportunities.ref
```

2)

```
SELECT opportunities.ref,
CASE WHEN opportunities.ref IS NOT NULL THEN ''''+opportunities.ref+'''' END
FROM opportunities
GROUP BY opportunities.ref
```

Answer (score 3):

In case ref column is an integer, you can use

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN opportunities.ref IS NOT NULL
           THEN '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ref) + ''''
       END
FROM opportunities
GROUP BY opportunities.ref;
```

In case you need the entire converted column in a single string separated by a comma

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)= '';
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX);
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM opportunities
)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @listStr = @listStr + tbl_opportunities.ref + ','
        FROM
        (
            SELECT '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ref) + '''' AS MarketSeq
            FROM opportunities
        ) tbl_opportunities;
        SELECT @result = SUBSTRING(@listStr, 1, LEN(@listStr) - 1);
END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @result = '';
END;
SELECT @result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this escape sequence \".Usually we do this to escape from unwanted quotes.In your case this works well.

Answer (score 0):

I can never remember the escape sequence so I tend to use the ascii code

```
declare @opportunities table (ref varchar(10))
insert into @opportunities values
('op10'),('op10'),('op10'),
('op20'),('op254')

SELECT 
CASE WHEN ref IS NOT NULL THEN concat(char(39),ref,char(39))
else ref
end  ref
FROM @opportunities
GROUP BY ref
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN opportunities.ref IS NOT NULL THEN ''''+CAST(opportunities.ref as varchar)+'''' END as 'ColumnName' FROM opportunities GROUP BY opportunities.ref
```

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres, you can do the following.

```
SELECT 
    ''''|| p.billto_name_first ||''''
FROM
    payments p
WHERE
  id = $id
```